# Accessing products associated to subscriptions with stripe API

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

Im trying to do something very simple with my stripe account and the Stripe API. I have a large list of subscriptions (3000+), and I need to retrieve all of the product ID's that are associated with the said subscriptions.

I've setup a simple node/express app with a router like this:

```
router.get('/getproducts', async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
      for await (const subscription of stripe.subscriptions.list()) {
        var data = subscription["data"]
        console.log(subscription["data"]);
        //need to do more:
        //get product id out of the data object here
        //save in an array 
      }
      next();
    } catch(err) {
      next(err);
    }
});
```

Right now all I'm trying to do is display the data object out of the subscription info and I keep seeing 'undefined' in the console. Am I not accessing the data object correctly? It's coming in as JSON and I thought this was the proper way of accessing the data.

I am very new to node/javascript so please bear with me as I'm trying to wrap my head around all of this!